# Effectiveness of Secure Boot on kernel-mode rootkit detection

Tags: antivirus, detection, rootkits, kernel

With so many new patches and updates, how effect is Secure Boot on detecting kernel-mode rootkits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secure Boot consists of several components working together ( https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn168167.aspx was my source for how the different components work). Because it works vertically (from the bootloader up) the security of the kernel-mode protection the requires that the lower levels work flawlessly.

1. Secure Boot

   - When the PC is turned on the UEFI Bios finds the bootloader. The Bios will only run the bootloader if the bootloader is signed using a trusted certificate or the user has approved the bootloader's digital signature. This prevents and modified/unofficial bootloaders, theoretically stopping bootkits. However this only works if the security is implemented correctly. A little Googling finds several reports of methods that allow a program to bypass the Secure Boot.

     - http://www.pcworld.com/article/2337180/new-attack-methods-can-brick-systems-defeat-secure-boot-researchers-say.html
     - http://www.pcworld.com/article/2045793/researchers-demo-exploits-that-bypass-windows-8-secure-boot.html
     - http://www.pcworld.com/article/2948092/security/hacking-teams-malware-uses-uefi-rootkit-to-survive-os-reinstalls.html
     - http://www.intelsecurity.com/resources/pr-bios-secure-boot-attacks-uncovered.pdf

     I will leave the evaluation of these articles as a exercise to the reader. In addition there seem to be articles that reference bugs in the UEFI implementation of several motherboards. If we assume that these exploits exist then all further Secure Boot steps are compromised, including the Kernel mode root-kit protection.
2. Trusted Boot

   - The bootloader then verifies the digital signature of the kernel. Then the kernel verifies the Windows start process. This includes the kernel drivers, the startup files and the ELAM system. If any of these files are corrupted then the computer automatically tries to repair/replace them. If this fails the computer refuses to boot. However this assumes that the bootloader was secured. If that step was compromised then this one could be bypassed as well.
3. Early Launch Anti-Malware (ELAM)

   - ELAM starts antivirus software before non-Microsoft boot drivers are loaded. Once ELAM is started it scans drivers as they load. This theoretically prevents malware infected drivers from hiding themselves from the Anti-Virus software, which is normally  not loaded until after boot. ELAM can load either a Microsoft (Windows Defender, Endpoint ect.) or a non-Microsoft anti-malware driver. If a driver contains malware or is not trusted then ELAM will prevent it from loading. This is secure to the point that you trust the anti-virus software to detect driver exploits and malware, which is not guaranteed with new exploits.
4. Measured Boot

   - Measured Boot does not prevent exploits, instead it helps in their detection. Using Measured Boot Windows sends logs about the boot process to a secure server. This includes hashes of the boot files allowing any changes to be detected. In order for this to work you need to a. have a secure server setup and b. actively monitor the boot logs.

These potential issues do not mean that Secure Boot does not work. I found very few references to functioning rootkits or bootkits for UEFI systems in the wild. In addition the Microsoft Security Intelligence Reports 18 or 19 (https://www.microsoft.com/security/sir/default.aspx) do not report any rootkits or bootkits. Of course they also make no claims in the reports that Secure Boot fixed these issues.